# recover netbeans .java file

Tags: java, netbeans, file-recovery

Is there a way to recover unsaved .java file in netbeans? My computer suddenly booted off without me running my code. The file now looks like this

[image]

Comment: Click right button on the package -> history -> revert deleted

Comment: try hack: create empty file with same name and then use version (local history)